# Creativity needed for constructing differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, biology

For my question, I'm given a situation where I let $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ represent the population sizes of two discrete species. The scenario I'm attempting to model goes something like this:

> When both populations are isolated from each other, the groups grow, but there are limited resources. Also, the relationship between these two species is **cooperative**.

With that description in mind, my task is to come up with with a system of differential equations that models this. I've worked with species that don't benefit from each other through interactions, like foxes and rabbits, but this situation is a bit different. If I'm interpreting this correctly, the species will both benefit through interactions and during isolation, correct? I have an idea of what my system of differential equations should look like. So, I have

$$\frac{dy}{dt} = \fbox{numbers involving variables x and y} + kxy$$ 
$$\frac{dx}{dt} = \fbox{numbers involving variables of x and y} + kxy$$

Here, I let $k \in \mathbb{R^+}$ except the number $0$. In terms of the species that I can use to model my system, what about clown fish and sea anemone? Thoughts and inquiries are welcome here.

Comment: A classical choice for the evolution of an isolated population $z$ growing for small values of the population but with limited resources is the logistic dynamics $$\dot z=rz\left(1-\frac zK\right)$$ with  capacity $K$ and Malthusian parameter in sparse populations $r$. Thus, you are probably expected to provide dynamics similar to $$\dot x=rx\left(1-\frac xK\right)+kxy\qquad \dot y=sy\left(1-\frac yL\right)+\ell xy$$ with $(r,s,K,L,k,\ell)$ all positive.

Comment: @Did This looks promising. As for the species that could model such a system that you just mentioned, any particular ones come to mind? I mentioned clown fish and sea anemone in my OP (if correct, perhaps more examples would be insightful for everyone).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a spin on the classical Lotka - Volterra system.

My first impulse would be to try a model such as the following:
$$
x'=x(a+by) \\
y'=y(c+dx)
$$

Where $a,b,c,d$ are positive terms.

$a$ and $c$ represent the reproduction rate when the populations are isolated, while $b$ and $d$ represent the cooperation between the two species (which is proportional to the number of interactions, itself proportional to the population of both species, thus the $b$,$d$ terms must go together with the product of the variables $xy$ ).

$b$, $d$ could be the same as in your question, though it does not really simplify the system too much and in general the benefits do not have to be symmetric for both species.

For the species choice, clown fish and anemone look good :)

Comment: Hi Jsevillamol. I'll definitely have to read more about the Lotka-Volterra system. Our professor has not brought that up yet (maybe he will not sure sure just yet), but this also looks promising I believe.